# Open File Dialog in Android?

Tags: android, openfiledialog

Can I use OpenFileDialog in Android? I want to choose image from OpenFileDialog and save image to a SQLite database and resource folder. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [link](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html) helped me

I have created `FolderLayout` which may help you.

#### folderview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/path" android:text="Path"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/list"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### FolderLayout.java

```
package com.testsample.activity;




   public class FolderLayout extends LinearLayout implements OnItemClickListener {

    Context context;
    IFolderItemListener folderListener;
    private List<String> item = null;
    private List<String> path = null;
    private String root = "/";
    private TextView myPath;
    private ListView lstView;

    public FolderLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;


        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.folderview, this);

        myPath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);
        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        Log.i("FolderView", "Constructed");
        getDir(root, lstView);

    }

    public void setIFolderItemListener(IFolderItemListener folderItemListener) {
        this.folderListener = folderItemListener;
    }

    //Set Directory for view at anytime
    public void setDir(String dirPath){
        getDir(dirPath, lstView);
    }


    private void getDir(String dirPath, ListView v) {

        myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
        item = new ArrayList<String>();
        path = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        if (!dirPath.equals(root)) {

            item.add(root);
            path.add(root);
            item.add("../");
            path.add(f.getParent());

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];
            path.add(file.getPath());
            if (file.isDirectory())
                item.add(file.getName() + "/");
            else
                item.add(file.getName());

        }

        Log.i("Folders", files.length + "");

        setItemList(item);

    }

    //can manually set Item to display, if u want
    public void setItemList(List<String> item){
        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                R.layout.row, item);

        lstView.setAdapter(fileList);
        lstView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        File file = new File(path.get(position));
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            if (file.canRead())
                getDir(path.get(position), l);
            else {
//what to do when folder is unreadable
                if (folderListener != null) {
                    folderListener.OnCannotFileRead(file);

                }

            }
        } else {

//what to do when file is clicked
//You can add more,like checking extension,and performing separate actions
            if (folderListener != null) {
                folderListener.OnFileClicked(file);
            }

        }
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        onListItemClick((ListView) arg0, arg0, arg2, arg3);
    }

}
```

And an Interface `IFolderItemListener` to add what to do when a `fileItem` is clicked

#### IFolderItemListener.java

```
public interface IFolderItemListener {

    void OnCannotFileRead(File file);//implement what to do folder is Unreadable
    void OnFileClicked(File file);//What to do When a file is clicked
}
```

Also an xml to define the row

#### row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowtext" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="23sp" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

### How to Use in your Application

In your xml,

#### folders.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="1">
    <com.testsample.activity.FolderLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" layout="@layout/folderview"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:layout_width="200dp" android:id="@+id/localfolders"></com.testsample.activity.FolderLayout></LinearLayout>
```

In Your Activity,

#### SampleFolderActivity.java

```
public class SampleFolderActivity extends Activity implements IFolderItemListener {

    FolderLayout localFolders;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        localFolders = (FolderLayout)findViewById(R.id.localfolders);
        localFolders.setIFolderItemListener(this);
            localFolders.setDir("./sys");//change directory if u want,default is root   

    }

    //Your stuff here for Cannot open Folder
    public void OnCannotFileRead(File file) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setTitle(
                "[" + file.getName()
                        + "] folder can't be read!")
        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {


                    }
                }).show();

    }


    //Your stuff here for file Click
    public void OnFileClicked(File file) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {


                    }

                }).show();
    }

}
```

Import the libraries needed. Hope these help you...

Answer (score 3):

Check this [Android File Dialog](http://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/)

I hope you know how to download the source... You might need a program like [tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html)

Answer (score 0):

[OpenFileDialog](https://github.com/sebdomdev/OpenFileDialog) is a custom dialog I wrote. You pretty much just have to call

```
new OpenFileDialog().show();
```

to get what you want.